# Not sure about PCA in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I need to do some PCA using sklearn and I want to make sure I do it the right way. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(data)

eigenvalues = pca.singular_values_
print(eigenvalues)

x = pca_result[:,0]
y = pca_result[:,1]
```

The data looks like this:

```
[[ -6.4186, -14.3534,  18.1296,  -2.8110,  14.0298],
[ -7.1220, -17.1501,  21.2807,  -3.5025,  16.4489],
[ -8.4652, -18.9316,  25.0303,  -4.1773,  18.5066],
...,
[ -4.7054,   6.1389,   3.5146,  -0.1036,  -0.7332],
[ -5.8533,   9.9087,   4.1178,  -0.5211,  -2.2415],
[ -6.2969,  13.8951,   3.4365,  -0.9207,  -4.2024]]
```

These are the eigenvalues: `[1005.2761  ,  853.5491  ,   65.058365,   49.994457,   10.277865]`. I am not totally sure about the last 2 lines. I want to plot the data projected in the 2D space that seems to make up for most of the variation in the data (basically make a 2D plot of the 5D data, as it seems like it lives on a 2D manifold). Am I doing it right? Thank you!

Comment: This is more a question for stats.stackexchange.com but I think that if you are planning to use only two components, you need to fit only two. Fitting 5 components and plotting two might not make sense, I believe it would have different factor loadings.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I am a bit confused. Isn't PCA meant to take into account the variation on all the axis, and show the most important ones? For example if I do pca = PCA(n_components=2), I still get the same values for the eigenvalues of the first 2 main components. It's just that the other 3 are not computed, but the numbers for the main 2 are the same.

Comment: I think you may be right actually. But you have the data so you can do the test. Be sure to let me know

Comment: @NicolasGervais with 2 components I am getting [1005.2762,  853.5494] for eigenvalues. With 5 I am getting [1005.2761  ,  853.5491  ,   65.058365,   49.994457,   10.277865]. Not sure if there are some roundoff errors, or the first 2 are really identical.

Comment: They're identical. Cool!

Comment: @BillKet Yes, your last two lines are fine. That is exactly how you can get the first two components for plotting. (The [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html) uses a similar approach, although it's a bit hard to read...) Does this answer the question (i.e. were you just looking for verification) or is there more to your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Principal component analysis (PCA) is a statistical procedure that uses an orthogonal transformation to convert a set of observations of possibly correlated variables (entities each of which takes on various numerical values) into a set of values of linearly uncorrelated variables called principal components
>
> Such dimensionality reduction can be a very useful step for
>   visualising and processing high-dimensional datasets, while still
>   retaining as much of the variance in the dataset as possible. For
>   example, selecting L = 2 and keeping only the first two principal
>   components finds the two-dimensional plane through the
>   high-dimensional dataset in which the data is most spread out, so if
>   the data contains clusters these too may be most spread out, and
>   therefore most visible to be plotted out in a two-dimensional diagram;
>   whereas if two directions through the data (or two of the original
>   variables) are chosen at random, the clusters may be much less spread
>   apart from each other, and may in fact be much more likely to
>   substantially overlay each other, making them indistinguishable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

So you need to run:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(data)

x = pca_result[:,0]
y = pca_result[:,1]
```

Then you have a two dimensional space.